# Two Unauthorized login with php in one domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, server, unauthorized

I have a site with files in the root, this site is with a popup login via unauthorized in php, this login works well. 
I have another site in a folder in the root: root/admin_pi/, in this site I also have a popup login via unauthorized like the site in the root, 
I have a problem in the second site (root/admin_pi/) 
when I do login the site is loged in into the homepage but when I go to another page or I reload the homepage I see again the login popup, 
each time I change the a page I see again the login popup,
someone can help me to know how can I fix the conflict with the two logins? 
each site has a different .htaccess file with the line :
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

this is my php code to login:

```
function doLogin()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
    {
        if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
            $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
            $_SESSION['logged_in_password']=$password;
            $_SESSION['logged_in_username']=$user;

            header("location: ".HOME_PAGE);
            return;
        }
        else {
            showLoginBox();
        }
    }
    else
    {

    if(preg_match('/Basic+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $matches))
     {
         list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
     }

    $user = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] : '';
    $password = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] : '';
    $login_success = check_user_details($user, $password);
    if($login_success)
    {

        $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
        $_SESSION['logged_in_password']=$password;
        $_SESSION['logged_in_username']=$user;

        header("location: ".HOME_PAGE);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        session_unset($_SESSION['login']);
        showLoginBox();
    }
    }
}


function showLoginBox(){
    $_SESSION['login']=true;

    if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
     $_SESSION['logged_in_password']=$password;
     $_SESSION['logged_in_username']=$user;

        header("location: ".HOME_PAGE);
        return;
    }

   header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Admin Panel"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "You must enter a valid username and password to access this page\n";
    echo '<p><a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">Try again</a></p>';
    exit;
}
```

Thank you very much